# ActionbarSherlock Android prior 3.0: prevent showing tabs as dropdown

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, fragment, android-tabs

I have an `SherlockFragmentActivity` that holds three fragments. You should be able to access them as tabs via the ActionBar and everything works fine in Android versions past 3.0, but in prior versions i got the problem, that the tabs are not shown below the actual actionbar, but directly in the main part of it and as there isnt enough space, the three tabs are shown as dropdown menu (in portrait mode, in landscape there is enough space and the tabs are shown completely). 
I already applied the flag `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in my manifest, but nothing changed.
This is the way i setup the tabs in my `SherlockFragmentActivity`

```
private void setupTabs(int tabSelection) {
    actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.Tab buddyTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Contacts")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.buddys);
    ActionBar.Tab chatsTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Chats")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.chats);
    ActionBar.Tab schedularTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Schedular")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.schedular);


    buddysFragment = new BuddysFragment();
    chatsFragment = new ChatsFragment();
    schedularFragment = new SchedularFragment();

    buddyTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(this, "buddys", buddysFragment));
    chatsTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(this, "chats", chatsFragment));
    schedularTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(this, "schedular",
            schedularFragment));

    actionbar.addTab(buddyTab);
    actionbar.addTab(chatsTab);
    actionbar.addTab(schedularTab);
    Log.i("MainActivity Tab selection", "settings tab selection to " + tabSelection);
    actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(tabSelection);

}
```

Are there any possibilities i can force the tabs to show up like in android 3.x and 4.x, so below the actual actionbar?
Thanks in advance.

sMau